# Censored words from Narcos: Mexico Season 2

Tags: narcos-mexico

Why and what are the censored words from 2 episodes in particular of Narcos: Mexico Season 2 on Netflix USA as pointed out below?

2 Instances I could find in the scripts as well :

[**S2E4 The Big Dig:**](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=narcos-mexico-2018&episode=s02e04)

> Can you give us a name? My uncle.
>   [OVER INTERCOM.]
>   The Minister of Defense.
>   Could you give us his name, please? [BLEEP.]

[**S2E8 Se Cayo El Sistema:**](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=narcos-mexico-2018&episode=s02e08)

> That's how you rig an election without leaving a lick of evidence.
>   [IN SPANISH.]
>   Internal party polling confirms that voting outside Mexico City is down.
>   It's working.
>   At 8:00 p.
>   m.
>   , we'll have de la Madrid go on TV to call the election in [BLEEP.]
>   favor.
>   Good.
>   Once he's in office, I expect to be his first call.

Comment: I don't remember anything being censored in Narcos - might depend on 'broadcast' jurisdiction.

Comment: In S2:E4 a name is censored during a character's interrogation after he's asked to identify one of his powerful relatives. That's the only instance I can think of.

Comment: I've added specific instances in the script I was referring to to the original question

Comment: I had the same question! At least in Greece it was censored

Comment: +1 - if not for your question I would have forgotten about it. While watching I wondered if it was to avoid libelling real life living public figures but always became to caught up in the plot progression to retain the query. Fantastic question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, the Minister of Defense was Juan Arevalo Gardoqui.  He was profoundly corrupt, but the character Mister X amalgamates several figures.  Particularly, when the election system crashes the person in charge is Manuel Bartlett Diaz, who, amazingly is still around having experienced a come to Jesus moment and working with the current Mexican President (who, in theory, hails from the left and won on the promise of fighting corruption) as Director of the national electric company.  Still corrupt, as you can guess.

The bleeped out candidate is pretty clear cut, it's Carlos Salinas de Gortari. The actor is a dead ringer for the man so I don't understand what was gained by bleeping out the name unless, as stated, the bleeping comes from the tapes and reflects that.

Comment: @Joachim Their answer is that the censored words are actually people's names. This does actually answer the question.